# UITabBar multiline

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar with five UITabBarItems. I would like to have their titles multi line as normally defined by \n.

I've heard this requires a custom UITabBar, but I believe that is quite an overkill for such small change.

Is their an easier way than including a TabBar framework and to initialize a custom tabbar from scratch?

Comment: You heard correctly. Apple doesn't give you access to the underlying label to change its numberOfLines property, and since UITabBarItem doesn't inherit from UIView, you can't traverse its view hierarchy searching for it. (not a good solution anyway)

Comment: Is there any framework, where I can initialize the UITabBar via the storyboard as I do now, but have the ability to customize this?